# Getting typed return of method using java reflection

Tags: java, methods, reflection, return-type

If I have a class like so:

```
class Test {
    Thing<String> getThing(String thing) {}
}
```

how can I determine String.class using reflection on an instance of Test?
The path I want to take is new Test() -> get class -> find method -> get return type ->-> somehow get String.class, but I'm not finding how the last part is done. What I have so far gets me `Thing<java.lang.String>` but not the inner class.

```
import org.reflections.ReflectionUtils;

Iterables.getOnlyElement(ReflectionUtils.getAllMethods((new Test()).getClass())).getGenericType();
```

whereas `.getReturnType()` just gets me a `Thing.class`...

Comment: [Type erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html).

Comment: ok, im not seeing how to use that

Comment: what if its not a generic type, and it's always a String

Comment: Which `String` in `Thing<String> getThing(String thing) {}`? The `Thing<String>`, or the `String thing` *thing*?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch, basically you're wrong. Method and field declarations are not erased completely. They appear in compiled .class files (otherwise you would not be able to use normally any binary Java library) and available via reflection.

Comment: @TagirValeev I knew it wasn't erased completely, but that's a very nice addition in Java 8.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I mistakenly used wrong method in my answer. Edited now. Things are even simpler and work in Java 5 already. AnnotatedType is necessary if you want to read type annotations (like `Thing<@MyAnnotation String>`) which actually appeared in Java 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java you can get it using standard reflection API (no need to use `ReflectionUtils`). You correctly used `getGenericReturnType`. You just need to cast it to [`ParameterizedType`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/ParameterizedType.html):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchMethodException {
    Method m = Test.class.getDeclaredMethod("getThing", String.class);
    Type type = m.getGenericReturnType();
    // type is Thing<java.lang.String>
    if(type instanceof ParameterizedType) {
        Type[] innerTypes = ((ParameterizedType) type).getActualTypeArguments();
        if(innerTypes.length == 1) {
            Type innerType = innerTypes[0];
            if(innerType instanceof Class) {
                // innerType is java.lang.String class
                System.out.println(((Class<?>) innerType).getName());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @mathematician, actually it's even simpler (and works even in Java 1.5), check the updated answer.